# Is there any way to make WooCommerce REST API be friendly to customers?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building an e-shop on `WordPress` + `WooCommerce` and `Android` app that retrieving data from WooCommerce REST API. I'm using `WooCommerce`'s REST API with JWT to get information about products, categories, etc. also make orders, adding to cart, etc.

It's good, if you have admin's OAuth 1.0a credentials, but, I'm using customer's JWT. I made `WordPress` accept this auth method (by my plugin).

If I make request to `http://SERVER/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories`, I will get this error:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Вы не можете просматривать список ресурсов.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I'm passing `Authentification: Bearer "JWT"` and `WordPress` accept it, but `WooCommerce` don't give me any info.

How I made `WordPress` accept my JWT:

```php
function test_rest_user($result, $th, $request){
    $secret_key = defined('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY') ? JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY : false;

    $auth = $request->get_header_as_array("Authorization");
    if ($auth){
        $token = explode(" ", $auth[0])[1];

        $user = api::exchange_token_to_wp_user($token, $secret_key);
        if ($user){
            set_current_user($user->data->ID);
        }
    }
}
add_filter("rest_pre_dispatch", "test_rest_user", 10, 3);
```

The main topic of this question is that `WooCommerce` not accepting JWT. This is response from `WordPress` REST API with customers's JWT (`http://SERVER/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me`):

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "test",
    "url": "",
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://SERVER/author/test/",
    "slug": "test",
    "avatar_urls": {},
    "meta": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://SERVER/wp-json/wp/v2/users/7"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://SERVER/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'd temporal solution. I made function, that hooks `WooCommerce` REST API permissions, you can `Google` how to do that. It hooks from `woocommerce_rest_check_permissions` filter. Just check is user logged in and provide access to methods. It's so easy!